# Image scoping issue when using Wowchemy Hugo Academic and Blogdown workflow

Tags: html, r, hugo, blogdown

I was following ApresHill's amazingly helpful [blog post](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2020-12-new-year-new-blogdown/#step-4-create-content) for creating my website. I have a question regarding the image scoping, I would appreciate it if someone can shed some light. [Wowchemy tutorial](https://wowchemy.com/docs/content/writing-markdown-latex/#images) says the images can be placed under `/assets/media/` folder starting with Wowchemy v5.1. Prior to this release, they were to be found under `static` folder.

My question has to do with the difference in scoping when I'm referring to an image in the `yaml` front matter or within the post itself. In short, YAML headers scope for images in `/assets/media/` while post bodies scope for images in `static/media/`:

Let the image paths be:
`/assets/media/IMG_IN_ASSETS_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg`
`/static/media/IMG_IN_STATIC_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg`

```
---
# This works in YAML
  background:
    image: IMG_IN_ASSETS_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg
    image_darken: 0.65
    image_parallax: true
    image_position: center
    image_size: cover
    text_color_light: true
  spacing:
    padding: ["20px", "0", "20px", "0"]
---
```

```
---
# This doesn't work in YAML
  background:
    image: IMG_IN_STATIC_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg
    image_darken: 0.65
    image_parallax: true
    image_position: center
    image_size: cover
    text_color_light: true
  spacing:
    padding: ["20px", "0", "20px", "0"]
---
```

**When I try to insert an image to the post body only `static` folder is scoped**

```
# adding images under `static` folder works
![](/media/IMG_IN_STATIC_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg) # works 

# images under `/assets/media/` aren't found. I tried a few things here:
![](/media/IMG_IN_ASSETS_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg)
![](/assets/media/IMG_IN_ASSETS_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg)
![](../assets/media/IMG_IN_ASSETS_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg)
```

```
# It works when I use the shortcodes though

{{< figure src="IMG_IN_ASSETS_MEDIA_FOLDER.jpg" >}}
```

Why do the post front matter and body behave differently when it comes to image scoping? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I heard in the [R Studio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/image-scoping-issue-when-using-wowchemy-hugo-academic-and-blogdown-workflow/124277), this may be due to differences in where Hugo or Blogdown looks for images. It also explains why the shortcode worked for inserting an image from the `assets` folder.